# Bootstrap Typeahead onselect

Tags: javascript, typeahead

so, I am going crazy right now about such a simple problem: 
Once I select a "typeahead" it should redirect immediately to the belonging page.

Unfortunately, jsfiddle doesn't show the dropdown for some reason, so I uploaded it to a radom webspace. http://ch1n3s3.funpic.de/lol/test3.php

And this is the code:

```
<input id="id" autocomplete="off" name="name" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source='["test", "test2", "test3"]'>
<script>
$('#id').on('change', function(){
    var items = "'test', 'test2', 'test3'";
    var matchString = "'"+$(this).val()+"'";
    if (items.toLowerCase().indexOf(matchString.toLowerCase()) != -1){
        alert('Matched');
    }
    else {
        alert('Not Matched');
    }
});
</script>
```

Is there any solutuion which is easier than this and works better?

Thank you,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can write redirect request in the updater function provided by the typeahead , Give it a shot , its definitely better than this but not so easier .

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
$('.typeahead').bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
    window.location.href = '/' + suggestion;
});
```

For example, selecting the suggestion Alaska would redirect to /Alaska.